# Extract substring after a character if it exists, else returning the whole string, in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to find the simplest way to, in CMD, extract after either `/` or `\`, whichever comes last, if either are found, in a string.

For example:

*Input*

`apiserver_sdk`

*Expected*

`apiserver_sdk`

**or**

*Input*

`D:/dev/some/folder/GO/projectName`

*Expected*

`projectName`

I'm quite familiar with substr,substring from actual programming languages, but am unsure about it in shell languages like CMD.

Comment: Is the string with / or \ **always** a file path?

Comment: In my use cases, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that should work:

```
  echo %string% | findstr " / \ " >nul && for %%A in (%string%) do set string=%%~nA

before: apiserver_sdk  
after:  apiserver_sdk  

before: D:/dev/some/folder/GO/projectName
after:  projectName

before: c:\one\two three\four five
after:  five

before: "c:\one\two three\four five"
after:  four five
```